# Vuetify VGrid and transitions components breaking while building

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I recently updated vuetify from older version(1.2.8) to new version(1.3.2) and importing components by *A La carte*. It looks like below.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify, {
  VApp, // required
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VGrid,
  VFooter,
  VToolbar,
  transitions
} from 'vuetify/lib'
import { Ripple } from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VNavigationDrawer,
    VFooter,
    VToolbar,
    VGrid,
    transitions
  },
  directives: {
    Ripple
  }
});
```

I did same exactly like how documentation suggested. But I was getting the issue with VGrid and transitions while production build time. Because of this my layout breaking. can anyone help me on this.

Error :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the vuetify library, the code seems correct not sure why it's not working. Finally, what I did, I imported as like below only VGrid and Transitions components. Now it's working.

```
import VGrid from 'vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/';
import transitions from 'vuetify/lib/components/transitions/';
```